# A function to calculate the mean square error by cross-validation using cross_val_score

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I would like to write a function that allows me to calculate the root mean square error obtained by 5-sample cross-validation using the cross_val_score function of sklearn.model_selection.

(Knowing that the scoring argument of the cross_val_score()function allows to choose the metric we want to use.)

I found this method, but it does not correspond to the question :

```
def rmse(predictions, targets):
    return np.sqrt(((predictions - targets)**2).mean())
```

Thank you very much, Merci beaucoup :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply set `scoring='mean_squared_error'` in `sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score`. Check out the documentation for the [validator](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html) and the [metric](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#mean-squared-error).

In other words:

```py
cv = cross_val_score(estimator=my_estimator, X, y, cv=5, scoring='mean_squared_error')
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need a square-root of that value?

Comment: Some people like the RMSE (root of the mean squared error), some others like the MSE. In fact, some others like the Mean Absolute Error. I think it's just a matter of preference.

Answer (score 1):

Your using the wrong formula in your code, here is the correct formula for mean square error.

[image]

Y is the expected output, O is actual output from neural network.

Comment: I have try this, seems working : 

```def rmse_cv(model, X_train, y_train):
        MSE_CV_scores = -cross_val_score(model, X_train, y_train, cv=5,
        scoring='neg_mean_squared_error',
        n_jobs=-1)
        rmse_cv = np.sqrt(MSE_CV_scores).mean()
        return rmse_cv```

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

```
def rmse_cv(model):     
    rmse= np.sqrt(-cross_val_score(model, X, y, scoring="neg_mean_squared_error", cv=5))     
    return rmse
```

Comment: I have seen this many times on Kaggle. I don't understand why we need to use the negative sign and "neg_mean_squared_error" here.